# Loading current month calendar with function to change display with month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I have a calendar created so it should display the current month by default. I am able to do that with the text that represents the month that is being displayed, but having difficulty setting the date to the correct day of the week or showing the last x days of the previous month when the 1st of the current month starts on any day that is not Monday.

```js
function dayIncluded() {
    let defaultDisplay = document.querySelector(".calendar h2");
    let current = new Date();
    let year = current.getFullYear();
    // let month = current.getMonth();
    // let date = current.getDate();

    let monthName = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    let month = monthName.findIndex(i => i == defaultDisplay.textContent);
    if (month < 9) {
        month = '0' + (month + 1);
    }
    else {
        month = (month + 1).toString();
    }
    let monthStart = new Date(`${year}-${month}-01T00:00:00`);
    console.log('monthStart', monthStart);
    month = Number(month) - 1;
    let weekday = {
        0: 'Su',
        1: 'Mo',
        2: 'Tu',
        3: 'We',
        4: 'Th',
        5: 'Fr',
        6: 'Sa'
    };
    let dow = weekday[monthStart.getDay()];
    let numOfDaysFeb;
    if (year % 4 == 0) {
        numOfDaysFeb = 29;
    }
    else {
        numOfDaysFeb = 28;
    }
    let numOfDays = {
        'January': 31,
        'February': numOfDaysFeb,
        'March': 31,
        'April': 30,
        'May': 31,
        'June': 30,
        'July': 31,
        'August': 31,
        'September': 30,
        'October': 31,
        'November': 30,
        'December': 31
    };
    // let firstWeek = document.querySelector(".calendar table tbody tr td");
    switch (dow) {
        case 'Mo':
            console.log('mo');
            for (let i = 0; i < numOfDays[month]; i++) {
                document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[i].classList.toggle(`prev-month`);
                document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[i].textContent = `${i + 1}`;
            }
            break;
        case 'Tu':
            {
                console.log('tu');
                let i = monthName.findIndex((mo) => mo == defaultDisplay.textContent);
                // console.log('i', i);
                if (i == 0) {
                    i = 11;
                } else {
                    i -= 1;
                }
                for (let index = 0; index < numOfDays[monthName[i]]; index++) {
                    if (index == 0) {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].classList.toggle(`prev-month`);
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${numOfDays[i]}`;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${index + 1}`;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'We':
            {
                console.log('we');
                let i = monthName.findIndex((mo) => mo == defaultDisplay.textContent);
                // console.log('i', i);
                if (i == 0) {
                    i = 11;
                } else {
                    i -= 1;
                }
                for (let index = 0; index < numOfDays[i]; index++) {
                    if (index <= 1) {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#A1A5A1";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${numOfDays[i]}`;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${index + 1}`;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'Th':
            {
                console.log('th');
                let i = monthName.findIndex((mo) => mo == defaultDisplay.textContent);
                // console.log('i', i);
                if (i == 0) {
                    i = 11;
                } else {
                    i -= 1;
                }
                for (let index = 0; index < numOfDays[monthName[i]]; index++) {
                    if (index <= 2) {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#A1A5A1";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${numOfDays[i]}`;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${index + 1}`;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'Fr':
            {
                console.log('fr');
                let i = monthName.findIndex((mo) => mo == defaultDisplay.textContent);
                // console.log('i', i);
                if (i == 0) {
                    i = 11;
                } else {
                    i -= 1;
                }
                for (let index = 0; index < numOfDays[monthName[i]]; index++) {
                    if (index <= 3) {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#A1A5A1";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${numOfDays[i]}`;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${index + 1}`;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'Sa':
            {
                console.log('sa');
                let i = monthName.findIndex((mo) => mo == defaultDisplay.textContent);
                // console.log('i', i);
                if (i == 0) {
                    i = 11;
                } else {
                    i -= 1;
                }
                for (let index = 0; index < numOfDays[monthName[i]]; index++) {
                    if (index <= 4) {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#A1A5A1";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${numOfDays[i]}`;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${index + 1}`;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'Su':
            {
                console.log('su');
                let i = monthName.findIndex((mo) => mo == defaultDisplay.textContent);
                // console.log('i', i);
                if (i == 11) {
                    i = 0;
                } else {
                    i += 1;
                }
                for (let index = 0; index < numOfDays[monthName[i]]; index++) {
                    // console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td"));
                    if (index <= 5) {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#A1A5A1";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${numOfDays[i]}`;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
                        document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[index].textContent = `${index + 1}`;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

The parts that are especially difficult are:

- `let year = current.getFullYear();` intending to represent the year being displayed since the start of each month also changes depending on the year, but as of now I made it a constant for it only being 2023, so if the calendar displays December and the user clicks the button for next month, it'll display January 2023 instead of January 2024. I'm hoping to find a way for the latter result.
- `document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[i].classList.toggle(`prev-month`);` intending to toggle on or off the class `prev-month` with the main change being the color of text. As of now, it does not change.
- `document.querySelectorAll(".calendar table tbody tr td")[i].textContent =` ${i + 1}`;` intending to change the text being displayed to each date of the month. As of now, it does not change (or isn't even displayed after run).

The other switch cases have a different way of changing the color of text but that doesn't seem to work either.

How can I make it so, by using `dayIncluded()` when first being loaded and onClick of buttons the month's dates go under the correct day of the week and include the previous/future month's end/start dates that fit in the first/last week?

[This](https://github.com/leguchi/FinalFront_Hunter/blob/month-accuracy/src/components/views/HomePageView.js) is where I have the React HTML portion, in case this is also where the problem is.